# Identify the file type of a File / Stream - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, stream, file-type

I have a problem when I download a file from a URL (This it's not my main problem), the problem comes after that.
The file that I saved from the URL can be a image, doc, PDF or ZIP.

Exists some method to know the file type when the path doesn't has the extension?
Or identify the file type from an stream?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition - Framework.Net 3.5 - A Window App

```
Public Function DownloadFile_FromURL(ByVal URL As String, ByVal DestinationPath As String) As Boolean
    DownloadFile_FromURL = False

    Try
        Dim vRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim vResponse As Net.HttpWebResponse

        vRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(New Uri(URL))
        vRequest.Method = "GET"
        vRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        vRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        vResponse = vRequest.GetResponse

        If vResponse.ContentLength <> -1 Then
            Dim vLen As Long = vResponse.ContentLength
            Dim vWriteStream As New IO.FileStream(DestinationPath, IO.FileMode.CreateNew)
            Dim vStream As IO.Stream = vResponse.GetResponseStream()

            Dim vReadBytes() As Byte = New Byte(255) {}
            Dim vCount As Integer = vStream.Read(vReadBytes, 0, vReadBytes.Length)

            While vCount > 0
                vWriteStream.Write(vReadBytes, 0, vCount)
                vCount = vStream.Read(vReadBytes, 0, vReadBytes.Length)
            End While

            vWriteStream.Flush() : vWriteStream.Close()
            vResponse.Close() : vRequest = Nothing : GCcleaner()
            Dim v = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(DestinationPath)

            DownloadFile_FromURL = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.mc_GetAllExceptions)
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebRequest for the download.

```
Dim uri As String = "http://domain.com/resource"

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "GET"
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Dim contentType = response.ContentType
' this will have the content type/ file type
```

You can now have a routine to save the file using a particular extension depending on the content type. for instance a content type of "image/jpeg" can be saved as *.jpg

Comment: The ContentType is coming in blank...

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-BpICDrXzh5s/USlqRLshjfI/AAAAAAAAAjc/pN4ry8gFXuQ/s744/a.png

Another suggestion?

Comment: @MiBol Can you update your answer with your code to show how you are accessing the resource/url?

Answer (score 0):

For an Image you can load it into an Image() object and see if it throws an OutOfMemoryException -- not an image.

PDF you can read the first few bytes of it (the PDF file type info is stored there, though not sure exactly what it is at the moment).

ZIP and DOC I'm not sure about.

If you are using WebRequests you can grab the content type of the response stream. More information about the MIME/content types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx